# Java + Oracle + EntityManager

Tags: java, oracle, entitymanager

My problem is that I have a query with EntityManager like:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE");
```

and Java throws this exception:

```
error e: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(-1!=80)
```

I try this run this query in Oracle (PL/SQL) and I don't have any problem.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you try `em.createQuery("select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE nombre");` ?

Comment: I have an error to: error e: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE nombre]. Unknown entity type [OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE].

Comment: Its because you may have not added the `@Entity` and not mentioned the class in your persistence.xml. Add `@Table` annotation to your `@Entity` and  Also add entity to `persistence.xml`. If its not an entity just use the `em.createNativeQuery("select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE nombre");`

Comment: thanks!!! I used creativeNativeQuery, and all is correct!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you have (or rather don't have) is a JPQL query, it wouldn't run in Oracle, since only a JPA implementor can translate it to SQL. Conversely what runs in Oracle can't be run with `createQuery`, it would require `createNativeQuery`.

A correct JPQL query would be something like 
`select a.nombre from MyEntity a` where `MyEntity` is the entity class that maps to the `OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE` table (and it has a `nombre` field).

Answer (score 0):

First you were missing the `nombre` after the OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE which is the alias for the table. And as I've already mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267382/java-oracle-entitymanager/32268572#comment52414295_32267382), you need to check if the class used in the query is an Entity and you have used the `@Table` annotation in the `@Entity`. In your case the `OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE` is not an Entity so you need to use `em.createNativeQuery`

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select a.nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE a");
```

which roughly equals to this query `select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE`.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this war

```
Query q=getEntityManager().createQuery("select nombre from OTP_OPERACION_DETALLE");
List roles=q.getResultList();
if (roles.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
}
else {
    //Fetch the Record
}
```

Comment: i don't have this function!!

Comment: `getEntityManager()` is a factory method and `getResult()` will help to execute the query. You are talking about which function??